# Regex to get text in the middle of two marks

Tags: java, regex

First of all, thanks for the help, I´m stuck on this issue for one week. I google and searched it here, but have no Java response, only with Python and other language that I don´t know.

I´m using java to develop an application that search for a pair of string and get the text in the middle of these two words. The example:

```
<A name=1></a>Some text with break lines<A name=300></a>
```

The main issue is, I need to get the text between these two marcations  until . Grabe this text and add it to a StringBuffer.

I did this:

```
Pattern regex   = Pattern.compile("<A name=1><\\/a>((.|\\s)+?)<A name=300><\\/a>");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(htmlFileReading);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Finded");
    System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
}
```

It works, but when I try something bigger than, but not so big, it returns stack over flow error.

How can I get the text between these two marks? Thanks a lot, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Doesn't this work? And btw, `(.|\\s)+?` is the same as `.+?`.

Comment: Post the case where it doesn't work please.

Comment: It work, but give me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError. The htmlFileReading is a HTML file with these marks <A name=1></a>text with break lines<A name=300></a>. I need to get the text in the middlle, but it give me the error. Thanks.

Comment: This expression won't cause a StackOverflowError, you probably have some kind of endless recursion in your search method. Can you post it?

Comment: It´s in the main post, I think if I change the If for a while, may fix it...

Comment: Hi. The overwhelming recommendation here is that you don't parse HTML with regular expressions. See here for more '*helpful*' information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/626796

Comment: @Tharwen that always makes me laugh. Thanks. But seriously OP. [jsoup HTML parser](http://jsoup.org/) will make short work of your HTML file in 5 minutes. Regular expressions are just horrid and unmaintainable when you try to do data extraction from HTML.

Comment: Thanks but I´m reading it as txt file, but in the text file it has an HTML. It should not work just like a normal text?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain to be right, but try somethig like this to have 'light' recursion :

```
// .* before and after if needed
Pattern regex   = Pattern.compile(".*<A name=1><\\/a>(.*?)<A name=300><\\/a>.*");
System.output.println(regex.matcher(myStringToSearchInside).replaceAll("$1"));
```

*Edited for newLine include*

Comment: I need to get the content at the (.*) to extract it and work with it. Thanks

Comment: @RodrigoFerrari As it is, it extracts data between your tags, the first and last .* may be suppressed if you need only the central (.*).

Comment: It did not get the break lines :(

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to extract the text from the xml, it's recommended to use XSLT

Comment: It´s a text file with html inside.